# Loading my website is still slow after gzip, md5-call-cachefiles-in-server, unlimited cache control, need help in cacheing

Tags: php, javascript, html, apache, httprequest

So, I'm in to cache everything on my website called http://apolloinvest.hu.

I sending gzipped, optimized images, js, css, and everything also the whole site is gzipped, the JS files are loads deferred, with LAB, and everything must be fantastic, I also made a  browser cache. But my site is still loads for 1 sec to load any page, and not instantly do it.

Could you help me please, why?

My redbot andswer is: http://redbot.org/?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fapolloinvest.hu%2F
Google PageSpeed rank is 99/100 (Because I don't want to remove the comments from the jquery UI)

The answer for **CSS files**: http://redbot.org/?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fapolloinvest.hu%2Fda232d78aa810382f2dcdceae308ff8e.css

For **JS files**: http://redbot.org/?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fapolloinvest.hu%2F5ec01c6d8ca5258bf9dcef1fc6bfb38c.js

So to tell the true I dont know what is the matter, with my caching or my JSes. Thanks for the help guys.

Répás

Comment: Probably just the connection between you and the server, rather than some underlying issue.

Comment: Since when has a page load time of 1 second been anything to worry about?

Comment: Nop, to load my site is about 1200-1700 ms, but I have really fine loading speed, and if i cacheing everything, even the js, css, images, all of them, why i have to wait for 1 sec?

Comment: Because it's not a single site, it's an engine. And I'd like to make it bulletproof. So If i make a site for someone with 1000000 users, I don't want them wait, or buy ten servers. I want to cache everything in their machines.

Comment: And I'm a maximalist guy anyway.

Comment: And sometimes it's not just one sec, it's two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site is pretty fast as it is, but here are a few possible improvements:

- Directly render the HTML page instead of using JavaScript to do so. Put all the `<script>` elements at the bottom of the HTML document (just before `</body>`) so that the browser can render the page even before the JavaScript code is downloaded.
- You can concatenate all the JavaScript files into one. Currently, http://apolloinvest.hu/475a641fc1d70f7c92efa3488e27568f.js is just empty.
- If possible, serve static content such as JavaScript files and styles with `Cache-Control` and `Expires` headers far in the future.

A couple of unrelated notes:

- The site is [not valid HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fapolloinvest.hu). The additional overhead caused by the browser transforming it to valid HTML does not matter, but the readability (and compatibility) does.
- Your stylesheet is restricted to `screen`. When printed out (or viewed on another non-`screen` device), it [looks ugly](http://phihag.de/2011/so/apollo.ru.pdf).
- The site breaks for users without JavaScript. It's just showing a loading bar, forever.

Comment: It was empty because i renamed something in my DBs. That is the jQuery atm. :)

Comment: Static content is also in the future - or i just wanted to be. Thanks for the help I'll check it.

Answer (score 1):

> I sending gzipped, optimized images, js, css, and everything also the whole site is gzipped, the JS files are loads deferred, with LAB

**THAT IS exactly your problem.**
Instead of doing all that fancy stuff, you had to **profile** your application first, determine **a certain bottleneck** and then optimize the exact part that is causing the slowness.

Let me suggest you to start from the `"Net"` tab of `Firebug` where you can watch **actual response times** of the requests. It is very likely that your code runs FAST but some JS-based web-counter prevents the page from displaying immediately.

if it's 1 second that takes for the PHP code to execute - time to profile it. Xdebug or simple `microtime(1)`-based manual profiling can tell you where is the problem. Once you find it, you'll be able to ask more certain question here.

Comment: The server side is the fastest. About 200ms to generate the whole site, good-looking-urls, etc. I PHP side, everything is really fast, and that was the first I've checked. +1 for this.

Comment: well, what is the ping to your site?